# Segment filter is ignored

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to take audio and a still image and create 30 minute segments of video created from that still image plus those 30 minutes of audio.

This is what I have attempted to use:

`find audio/ -name '*.ogg' -execdir bash -c '\
ffmpeg -i ../white-144p.png -i {} \
-acodec libvorbis \
-af silenceremove=0:0:0:-1:0.7:-30dB \
-segment_time 1800 \
-f segment ../video/$(basename {} .ogg)_%03d.mp4' \;`

ffmpeg happily chugs on past the 30 minute mark and writes out the a video created from the still image and the entire audio file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segment muxer, by default, when operating on a video+audio output, only creates a new segment when it encounters a video keyframe once the segment_time has elapsed. FFmpeg is primarily a program for handling timed media i.e. video and audio. A single image is treated as a 25 fps video of 1 frame. In your case, you need to change that as follows:

```
find audio/ -name '*.ogg' -execdir bash -c '\
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 8 -i ../white-144p.png -i {} \
-acodec libvorbis \
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1800)" \
-af silenceremove=0:0:0:-1:0.7:-30dB \
-segment_time 1800 -shortest \
-f segment ../video/$(basename {} .ogg)_%03d.mp4' \;
```

`-loop 1 -framerate 8` generates an infinite 8 fps video stream out of the image.

`-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1800)"` forces ffmpeg to generate a keyframe at each 1800 seconds so that segments can be cut at precise intervals.

`-shortest` is added so that the command ends when the audio does - the video stream is infinitely long.

Comment: I noticed YouTube wouldn't accept it when splitting it up with another ffmpeg script. I look forward to trying this and seeing if both issues are resolved.